# How to increase the Size of the message box in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

I had written a line of code for the message box which need to shown up in my application, but unfortunately, i don't know like how to increase the size of the message box. Please help me in increasing the size of the message box.

Example: The example shows the exact line of code which i had written.

```
If MsgBox("Move to Next Batch ?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.No Then
    '[...]
End IF
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Simply you can't. The message box is a system component and the size increase with the contents (text, icons and buttons) in it. Your only solution is to create your own messagebox control.

Comment: I am ok, if the text, icons and buttons are increase also, no problem for me.

Comment: @chandu They do not get bigger, the box gets bigger *if* there is more for it to show (like more lines of text). It is not much work to create your own version of a message box form and use the [Form.ShowDialog Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.7.2) to show it (see the example in the link).